# Группировка элементов ассоциативного массива по значению элементов

Tags: php

Есть массив

```
array(3) {
[0] => array(2) {
    ["name"] => string(13) "Имя 1" 
    ["group"] => string(22) "Значение 1"
}
[1] => array(2) {
    ["name"] => string(13) "Имя 2" 
    ["group"] => string(26) "Значение 2"
}
[2] => array(2) {
    ["name"] => string(13) "Имя 3" 
    ["group"] => string(22) "Значение 1"
}
}
```

PHP-скрипт:

```
<?php foreach ($product_filters as $product_filter) { ?>
<div>
   <?php echo $product_filter['group']; ?>
   -
   <?php echo $product_filter['name']; ?>
 </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Нужно вывести в одном div масивы c "Значением 1", а в другом c "Значением 2" и так далее, что бы получилось вроде этого

```
<div>
Имя 1 - Значение 1
Имя 3 - Значение 1
</div>
<div>
Имя 2 - Значение 2
</div>
и т.д...
```

Comment: откуда берутся данные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
$product_filters[0]["name"] = "Имя 1";
$product_filters[0]["group"] = "Значение 1";
$product_filters[1]["name"] = "Имя 2";
$product_filters[1]["group"] = "Значение 2";
$product_filters[2]["name"] = "Имя 3";
$product_filters[2]["group"] = "Значение 1";

$items = [];
foreach($product_filters as $product_filter) {
  $items[$product_filter["group"]][] = $product_filter;
}
ksort($items);
foreach($items as $group) {
  echo "<div>";
  foreach($group as $filter) {
    echo "{$filter['group']} - {$filter['name']}<br />";
  }
  echo "</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$data = [
    [
        "name" => "Имя 1",
        "group" => "Значение 1"
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Имя 2",
        "group" => "Значение 2"
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Имя 3",
        "group" => "Значение 1"
    ],
];

$product_filters = [];
foreach ($data as $row)
{
    $product_filters[$row['group']][] = $row['name'];
}

foreach ($product_filters as $group => $names)
{
    echo '<div>';
    foreach ($names as $name)
    {
        echo $name.' - '.$group.'<br>';
    }
    echo '</div>';

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Еще можно использовать [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php).

php >= 5.4

```
$inputArray = [
    ['name' => 'Имя 1', 'group' => 'Значение 1'],
    ['name' => 'Имя 2', 'group' => 'Значение 1'],
    ['name' => 'Имя 3', 'group' => 'Значение 2'],
];

$resultArray = [];

array_walk($inputArray, function($item, $key) use (&$resultArray) {
    $resultArray[$item['group']][] = $item;
});

var_dump($resultArray);
```